# The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object

Tags: php, wordpress, session, session-variables

I'm getting an error, the full error is:

```
Fatal error: authnet_cart_process() [<a href='function.authnet-cart-process'>function.authnet-cart-process</a>]: The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition &quot;AuthnetCart&quot; of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in /home/golfetc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/sccp-2.4.0/authnet_functions.php on line 1266
```

I'm using session to store cart object in it and get it later at some point. The authnetCart is basically class for cart object.

```
// Check cart in session
    if(isset($_SESSION['AUTHNET_CART'])) {
        // Get cart from session
        $authnetCart = $_SESSION['AUTHNET_CART'];
        foreach($authnetCart->getCartItems() as $item) {  // Line#1266
            if ($item->getItemId() == $subscription_details->ID ) {
                $addNewItem = false;
                break;
            }
        }
......
```

You can see at line 1266, the code doesn't allow me to access its method. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How are you initially setting `$_SESSION['AUTHNET_CART']`?

Comment: include AuthnetCart class before unserializing it or provide __autoload as indicated by error message.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php

Comment: what is the var_dump() of $_SESSION['AUTHNET_CART']. if it does not come as an object, it might also cause the problem?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, I'm using single instance method to initialize the object: public static function getInstance() {
  // If the cart is not in the session, create one and put it there
  // Otherwise, get it from the session
  if (!isset($_SESSION['AUTHNET_CART'])) { 
   self::$authnetCartInstance = new AuthnetCart();
   $_SESSION['AUTHNET_CART'] = self::$authnetCartInstance;
  } else {
   self::$authnetCartInstance = $_SESSION['AUTHNET_CART'];
  }
  return self::$authnetCartInstance; 
 }

Comment: This is quite an old question but I realized this error happens because the serialized data doesn't take in the methods that the class has, only the data in it. Therefore making the new instance and unserializing it will add the methods to the object and such. :P

Answer (score 55):

You need to `include` / `require` the php with your class *BEFORE* `session_start()` like

```
include PATH_TO_CLASS . 'AuthnetClassFilename.php';
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['AUTHNET_CART'])) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: How would we do this if we  do not yet know the class that is stored in the session? I am using the session to store the user object if a user logs in, but users do not have to log in, so I am not loading the user class until the user logs in, and that occurs after the session starts.

Comment: Do you have a reference of why this is best practice in PHP?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your answer is in the error message.

Before unserializing AUTHNET_CART, include the class which defines it. Either manually, or using an autoloader.

```
include PATH_TO_CLASS . 'AuthnetClassFilename.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['AUTHNET_CART'])) {//...
```

It doesn't appear that you're actually unserializing it either (I'm assuming this was serialized before stuffing it into the session?)

```
if(isset($_SESSION['AUTHNET_CART'])) {
        // Get cart from session

        /** UNSERIALIZE **/
        $authnetCart = unserialize($_SESSION['AUTHNET_CART']);
        foreach($authnetCart->getCartItems() as $item) {  // Line#1266
            if ($item->getItemId() == $subscription_details->ID ) {
                $addNewItem = false;
                break;
            }
        }
...
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers in here actually solved this problem for me.

In this particular case I was using CodeIgniter and adding any of the following lines before the line that caused the error:

```
 $this->load->model('Authnet_Class');
```

OR

```
 get_instance()->load->model('Authnet_Class')
```

OR

```
 include APPPATH . '/model/Authnet_Class.php';
```

Did **not** solve the problem.

I managed to solve it by invoking the class definition in the **construct** of the class where I was accessing `Authnet_Class`. I.e.:

```
class MY_Current_Context_Class extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Authnet_Class');
    }
    // somewhere below in another function I access Authnet_Class ...
```

I now understand that the context where you access the `Authnet_Class` class, needs to have its definition present on the context's class construct (and not just before you invoke the properties of `Authnet_Class`).

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend this technique, but **there is a way to get around this error** :

```
if( get_class($myObject)=='__PHP_Incomplete_Class' )
    $myObject = unserialize(preg_replace('/^O:\d+:"[^"]++"/', 'O:'.strlen('MyClass').':"MyClass"', serialize($myObject)));
```

**Having a good site architecture is obviously the right solution**, but it can help temporarily until the problem is fixed

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an MVC framework with a front controller, you need to have your autoload statement before your session_start statement:

[front controller]

```
//Do this before session start because session has an object that will not work
// if the class has not been loaded already
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

//Start a session AFTER autoloading
session_start();
```