# CKFinder - Not recognizing session variables. PHP

Tags: php, session-variables, ckfinder

hopefully, someone can help out. Appreciation in advance.

I'm using CKFinder 3.4.1 on PHP 5.6. What I'm essentially trying to do is get it to recognize that a user has logged into my CMS and allow that user to use CKFinder using session variables. I have verified that just by setting the authentication to return true, CKFinder works, so it is set upright. I have also verified that the session id and its authentication variable from the PHP CMS page match the session id and the authentication variable in CKFinder.

The simplified code is:

```
// I have verified that this does not run when I've logged into the CMS<BR>
// If this did run, it would mean that someone is trying to access the CKFinder without logging<BR>
// into the CMS, and the isAuthenticated variable would not be 1 <BR>
if (!isset($_SESSION['theUser'])) <BR>
{<BR>
    require_once 'class/sql.php';               // SQL: loads from /php/inc global folder <BR>
    require_once '/site_constants.php';<BR>
    $myDB = new SQL();<BR>
    $_SESSION['theUser'] = new Riff\User($myDB);<BR>
}<BR>

$config['authentication'] = function () <BR>
{<BR>
    // I have dumped the session id and isAuthenticated here to a log. When logged into the CMS, the<BR> 
    //session ids match, and the isAuthenticated variable is 1<BR>
    return $_SESSION['theUser']->isAuthenticated;<BR>
};<BR>
```

Comment: What exactly is the error that you see? And in which line is it triggered?

Comment: Make sure `session_start()` was called before accessing any session variables

Comment: Marco, session_start() is being called in some code a little higher up. I also tried putting it right before the return $_SESSION['theUser']... just to be safe. Still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Noam. It's not so much an error other than CKFinder is telling me it's disabled for security reasons. I'm dumping both the session_id and isAuthenticated flag onto my page. I can then do the same to a log (right before returning the value from the $config function, and they'll match.

So in other words, the session id and authenticated flag set when a user logs into our CMS matches what the config function sees (which is dumped to the log). Hopefully I'm explaining it more or less correctly.

Comment: Aaaand, I figured it out. It looks like something was being cached. When I tried it again, I got a new error, and that led me to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664257/the-script-tried-to-execute-a-method-or-access-a-property-of-an-incomplete-objec/23332388
And that's exactly what I was doing. Sorry to waste everyone's time, but I really appreciate everyone trying to help me!